# React Native Maps - showsUserLocation not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps, location-services

I'm using [React Native Maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps) to show a map on ios/Android.

I'm yet to give it a proper test on Android but on ios I can't get the `showsUserLocation` prop to actually show the location dot.

I've followed the docs and made sure I added `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` with a description in the Info.plist file.

My Info.plist file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need to access your location to provide location specific points to visit</string>
    ...
</dict>
```

and my MapView is initialised like so:

```js
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={initial}
    mapType={mapType}
    onRegionChange={handleRegionChange}
    onMapReady={() => setRegionReady(true)}
    showsUserLocation={true} // here is what I thought should show it
    showsMyLocationButton={true}
>
    ... // markers rendered here
</MapView>
```

No location dot though. When the app loads it asks for permission to view location which I've granted and I've also checked in settings and it should have location access "when in use"

I've also tried setting the "Simulate Location" options in Xcode to London, United Kingdom but it still doesn't show.

Is there anything I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you set your location in the simulator > Features > Location > Custom Location settings?

Comment: I didn't have that set. I just set it now and rebootted and kick off a new build but that didn't work

Comment: Okay, just had to restart Xcode and the sim and do a fresh build again and that worked! Thank you!
If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your location in the simulator > Features > Location > Custom Location settings to be able to see your location marked on the map.